# Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1' - Running a Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

Got this error while trying to run the docker container from an image that packages `streamlit` and a `tensorflow` model built on a mac (no GPU).

Is there a way it can be avoided? It's a very lightweight demo app, no GPU required. The `streamlit` app runs just fine without the docker.

Docker run command: `docker run -p 8501:8501 streamlit-app:latest`

Error:

```
2021-09-07 03:50:47.745622: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-09-07 03:50:47.745696: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2021-09-07 03:50:47.745737: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (4dd4cd9e71e5): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2021-09-07 03:50:47.746146: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2021-09-07 03:50:47.760338: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2900000000 Hz
2021-09-07 03:50:47.761149: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f0188000b60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2021-09-07 03:50:47.761205: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

Comment: I simply installed the CPU version of TensorFlow as a workaround for this.

Comment: Put `libcuda.so.1` path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/of/libcuda.so.1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Thanks!